# Azure sql server failover listener points in C#

Tags: azure-sql-database, high-availability, azure-sql-server

I am using "Using two Azure regions for business continuity with minimal downtime" approach for highly available services using Azure SQL Database.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-designing-cloud-solutions-for-disaster-recovery#scenario-2-azure-regions-for-business-continuity-with-maximum-data-preservation

I have configured two webapps with traffic manager in different regions (one is using fg-name.database.windows.net connection string for R/W operations and other one is using fg-name.secondary.database.windows.net for Read only operations. Now please check below steps -

Step 1 - If my Primary sql server is working fine then my connectionstring (fg-name.database.windows.net) will also work for all read-write operations for primary webapp.

Step 2 - If my primary sql server down (or region down) and I have set grace period as 1 hour then traffic manager will use second web app where I am using fg-name.secondary.database.windows.net connection string so users can perform read only operations within that 1 hour.

Step3 - After 1 hour when fail over starts and then again I need to change my connectionstring from fg-name.secondary.database.windows.net to (fg-name.database.windows.net) in secondary webapp so users can perform read-write operations.

I am facing problem that on which bases I can change connectionstring from read-only to read-write and again read-write to read only in c# application. Do I need to check number of SQLexceptions?

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can go for automatic failover groups and use the same R/w across both the primary and secondary region so if it goes down azure will do a failover automatically to secondary. And you can use the failover r/w listener as connection string and you no need to change anything in the connection string manually.